# Visa payWave, MasterCard PayPass and ExpressPay, NFC and RFID

Tags: rfid, smart-card, nfc

1. Since all those technologies use RFID contactless smart card and
   EMV, are they compatible? Is contact-less Visa card compatible with the
   Mastercard system?
2. Are the systems compatible with NFC? I.e. can the smartphone with NFC controller and antenna emulate e.g. Visa smart card either in SIM card or built-in secure element?

Comment: Yes both question. But you will never know how to emulute a Visa or master cards, the same way you dont know how to communicate with chip cards..

Comment: Hi, sure I do not know - but they both using EMV standard... I am not going to emulate it by myself, i was just curious if some company with cooperation with bank or card issuer can deliver the NFC solution which is compatible with existing systems...

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. They are all part of the same association.
2. Yes. The PayPass, et. al. cards are embedded with an RFID inlay that meets ISO 14443-A and ISO 14443-B standards and operates at 13.56MHz (same as cell phones)[[1]](http://www.rfidjournal.com/article/view/1420).

Just because they have the physical layer, however, does not mean that this will be supported for cell phones due to the security risk it represents. Some payment solutions and near-field companies have implemented their own payment systems on top of NFC independent of EMV [[2]](http://square.com) [[3]](http://tagstand.com).